# What are some good photography books available to read on Kindle?

Tags: books, photobooks

I do most of my reading on a Kindle, and find it very convenient. However, it seems that few publishers of photography books are making their titles available on Kindle. I'd be interested in reading photographers' memoirs and technical 'how-to' books on Kindle -- in other words, books about photography that are not entirely reliant on photographic illustrations. Does anyone have recommendations for good photography books that are available in mobi or epub format suitable for an e-reader?

Comment: For example, Susan Sontag's "On Photography" doesn't appear to be available in electronic format.

Comment: Generally speaking the topic of the question is something I am also interested in, but unfortunately it does not fit the format of a Q&A site such as this, and as such it is likely to get closed. See: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask For example, how will you choose a "best" answer, when all are likely to be just as valid? Also, over time the answers will change significantly. This is really a discussion question and has no real problem to be solved.

Comment: The question I have to your question is this:  how can a photography book, which tends to have pictures and color in it, be really as good or as useful in the type of format that a Kindle would display illustrations in?  I think if there is such a book, I'd be super interested in it, but until then I tend to read everything EXCEPT photography books on the Kindle.

Comment: You can read Kindle books on the iPad which has a great display.

Answer (score 2):

I enjoy books from the publisher [Craft & Vision](http://craftandvision.com/).  They are sold directly from their website in PDF.  From there you can import it into the Kindle application for easy synchronization.

[Kelby Training](http://kelbytraining.com/books/) is another publisher that produces great books but are more of the basics of digital photography but they also have a huge repository of training videos.  I believe they soley produce PDF books as well but they usually start out more than Craft & Vision's.

Comment: Thanks, those are good tips. I'm particularly interested in the mobi or epub formats instead of PDF.

Comment: You can use a tool like Calibre (http://calibre-ebook.com/download) to convert the source file to the epub or mobi.

Answer (score 1):

I have the [photographers eye](https://kindle.amazon.com/work/the-photographers-eye-ebook/B001G7IBVG/B002BL3HWY). It focuses on composition and gives very good examples.

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded the sample and will take a look.